# Is possible $\sqrt{I\cap J}\subset \sqrt{IJ} $ for $I,J$ Ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $I, J$ ideals of a commutative ring $R$. Is possible $\sqrt{I\cap J}\subset \sqrt{IJ} $ ?...or, is possible modify the hypothesis so that inequality is correct?

I tried to prove or find a counterexample but, I did not succeed...

Comment: How about: if $f^n \in I \cap J$, then $f^{2n} = f^n \cdot f^n \in IJ$?

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, $\sqrt{I\cap J}=\sqrt{IJ}$.

While $\supseteq$ follows immediately from the inclusion $I\cap J\supseteq IJ$, $\subseteq$ requires a different idea. Let $x\in\sqrt{I\cap J}$, meaning there is some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $x^n\in I\cap J$. But then $x^{2n}=x^nx^n\in IJ$ (as considered also by *Daniel Schepler* in the comments), since $x^n\in I$ and $x^n\in J$, and consequently $x\in\sqrt{IJ}$.

This is interesting in so far the radical bridges the gap between $I\cap J$ and $IJ$ as in general, even in very well-behaved rings such as $\mathbb Z$, we have $I\cap J\ne IJ$ (indeed, consider $I=J=\langle2\rangle\subset\mathbb Z$).

Comment: Thanks a lot!...your answer enriched me

Comment: @JELV Glad to help! :)